# Redirect to the same page that user tried to access before login - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

When a user tries to view a private page(/products/1/edit), he will be redirected to the login component.

After login i want to redirect the user to the same product edit page. **The problem is that I am unable to get the location props in the component. It is returning as undefined.
** The code is as follows.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppRouter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

AppRouter.js

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';

...  

class AppRouter extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkAlreadyLoggedIn();
  }

  render() {
    const { token, location } = this.props;
    return ((
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Layout style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/login" render={ () => token && <Redirect to=
              {
                location.state && location.state.from ? location.state.from.pathname :
                 "/dashboard"
              } /> || <Login />} />

                  <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}  />

...
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Layout>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    ));
  }
}
```

history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();
export default history;
```

i am already defined the private route as follows

```
class PrivateRoute extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    token: PropTypes.string,
    component: PropTypes.any
  }
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;
    let token = utils.getUserToken();
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={ () =>
          (token && <Component {...this.props} />) ||
          <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: this.props.location }
          }}/>
        }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Only if i get the location.state.from.pathname, i will be able to redirect the user to the page that he tried to access prior to login.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the `PrivateRoute` implementation I use and it performs redirect:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { isLoggedIn } from '../../utils/authHelper';


class PrivateRoute extends React.Component {
  renderComponent = () => {
    const { path, component: Component } = this.props;
    return (
      isLoggedIn()
      ? <Component {...this.props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: path }
        }} />
    )
  }

  render (){
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route {...rest} render={this.renderComponent} />
    )
  }

}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And usage is like:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
  <PrivateRoute path='/profile' component={ProfileComponent} />
</Switch>
```

And on `/login` route you will get the original url via `this.props.location.state.from`:

```
...  

doLogin(username, password)
.then(() => {
  window.location.href = `/${this.props.location.state.from}`;    
});
```

Comment: Interesting, how does that Redirect the user to the previous page after they have logged in though?

Comment: Let me check... Oh yes, I missed this part, I complete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using react hooks useHistory() method history.goBack()

```
    ...
    login(userData);
    history.goBack();
```